# PHP export results from SELECT query to a file and import it back?

Tags: php, sql

I need to save the result of a query to my server in a file format that can be easily imported back to the table in case it needs to be restored.

This is my query:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts")
```

How can  I create a file in my server with PHP and save the results of this query? And how can I restore the file to the table?

Comment: If you have access to phpmyadmin you can do this very easily.

Comment: yeah, but I need to automate it

Answer (score 0):

use [serialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to convert the object to string to save it in the file.
and [unserialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to convert the string into object again after loading the file content.